# Using fnctl() to lock and unlock file for read and write (multiple Processes)

Tags: c, linux, client-server

I am currently trying to implement a concurrent server (i.e. handling multiple processes by forking new child processes).

Each of the clients perform read/write requests to read from a file.txt located in the server.  I am currently using `fnctl()` to handle syncronization, ie. I can have multiple reads but only one write.

This is a sample code of what I have done till now:

```
{
    FILE *file = fopen("file.txt", "w+");

    fd = fileno(file);

    printf("\nThis is the file descriptor : %d\n", fd);

    if(file == NULL)
    printf("File cannot be opened");

    printf("\nLocking!!!!");

    //initliazing the flock structure
    memset(&lock, 0, sizeof(lock)); //setting 0 as a value
    lock.l_type = F_WRLCK;  //F_RDLCK, F_WRLCK, F_UNLCK
    lock.l_whence = SEEK_SET;  //SEEK_SET, SEEK_CUR, SEEK_END
    lock.l_start = 0;   //offset from l_whence
    lock.l_len = 0;   //length, 0 = to EOF
    lock.l_pid = getpid(); //the processes's PID


    //placing a write lock on the file
    fcntl(fd, F_SETLKW, &lock);

    printf("\nLocked-------");

    fwrite(buff + 1, 1, strlen(buff) - 1, file);
    //lock_realease(&l);
    printf("\nHit enter to unlock the file !");
    getchar();

    printf("\nFinished writing so we can unlock file !");

    //Releasing lock
    lock.l_type = F_UNLCK;  //unlocks the region of the file
    fcntl(fd, F_SETLKW,&lock);

    printf("\nFile unlocked!");
}
```

Can someone guide me if I am in the right direction please?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe. You'll have to add error handling (so you notice when locking failed), waiting (when locking failed) and timeouts (when another child is stuck and the lock is never released).

But in my experience, this process is brittle. Create a single socket instead. Let the children connect to the socket. Then use a master process to feed commands to the children. In this scenario, the master process replaces the single file.

This has a couple of advantages:

- The master process keeps tab on the state of the children (what they are working on) and you can write a tool to see this statistics. Later, you can use this for health monitoring.
- You don't need locking with sockets.

Comment: Can you give me some guidelines on how to perform such error handling and waiting please?

Comment: For the error handling, you need to check the manual for the functions that you call. Usually, you have to check the return values of all the functions that you call. For waiting, this is more complex. You need to find a function that lets your child sleep and a loop and some way to notice when you've waited too long.

Comment: I have performed error handling on functions as told.  However, I am still not clear minded regarding the wait function.  Should I implement a wait which wait for the status of the lock to go to "unlock"? I thought that this functionality is performed by the F_SETLKW. It blocks the other write processes and when the file is unlocked, the next block process waiting obtains the lock, no?  Thanks for your help!

Comment: Ah, you're right. `F_SETLKW` blocks. That means you need an alarm to do the timeout. Here is some code: http://www.unix.com/programming/47030-interrupt-blocking-lock-f_setlkw.html

Comment: Ok, I saw the post..but does it mean I need to create a signal handler...as just to let you know we have to adhere to a predifined header so we cannot create new methods....any feedback?

Comment: What do you plan to do when a single child process hangs and never releases the lock?

Comment: That's right, so I need a type of signal handler right?

Comment: Yes. Use `alarm(2)` to get a `SIGALRM` signal after a defined amount of time or to cancel a pending alarm. That way, you can implement a timeout for the lock.